# Convention for compiling and executing Java apps from shell?

Tags: java, javac

What is the convention that is followed for compiling and executing Java apps from the shell?  As a specific use case, I'm teaching some kids how to read Java source and picked [minicraft](https://github.com/shylor/miniventure) (which is a commented version of Notch's Ludum Dare 22 entry).  This is pretty exciting for them, but I've had my feet out of the Java realm for about 10 years and frankly I'd like to simultaneously teach them how to use the shell and less robust (ie, non IDE) editors before jumping into Eclipse and such.  I'd like to understand:

A) What shell command would you execute to compile and run the app (and from which project folder; ie, `miniventure` or `miniventure/src` or `miniventure/src/com/mojang/ld22`) and

B) what is the rationale to follow in knowing how to craft projects and the shell `java` and `javac` args for future reference when digging into other projects from src such as this?

Comment: @ylluminate I will take a look at it sometime this weekend. I have alot going on, so not exactly sure when, but it's no sweat -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the constraint to only work within a command shell, the best way to handle compiling is to run *javac* from the root of your classpath, right at the directory that contains whatever the top level package you have defined for your source code (looks like it is probably `miniventure/src` in your case). You can just run *javac* and use the `-cp` (short for classpath) command line argument to define the root of your classpath. Since you are teaching new programmers, you could use the long form of the same option, `-classpath` to reinforce that they are setting a Java classpath.

If you run *javac* from the root of your classpath, it's customary to just use a dot to reference that same directory: `javac -cp .`; because javac will traverse the directory (package) structure to find all source files (anything that has the .java filename extension), but the docs for javac recommend a more structured approach:

> There are two ways to pass source code file names to **javac**:
>
> - For a small number of source files, simply list the file names on the command line.
> - For a large number of source files, list the file names in a file, separated by blanks or line breaks. Then use the list file name on the **javac** command line, preceded by an **@** character.

If you run *javac* this way, it will place the class files next to the source files, but then the class files are all mixed in with the source files and may be scattered through the directory/package structure. The customary way to handle this is through the use of the *javac* `-d` command line argument, which defines the directory where compiled classes should be written; *javac* will preserve the package structure and create whatever directory structure is necessary during compilation. The standard way to define this option always was a directory named: `classes` that is a sibling to the source (or `src` in your case) directory. So you would create a new directory: `miniventure/classes` and then your command line would include: `-d ./classes`.

Since you're teaching new programmers, you will want to include debugging information during the compile, so when they run into errors or exceptions, the stack trace will include detailed debugging information. The *javac* command line option for this is: `-g` which will generate the class files with **all** debugging options turned on; this will include the following debugging options:

**source** which includes source file debugging information

**lines** which includes line number within the source file debugging information, and

**vars** which includes local variable debugging information

And finally, since it may be helpful to let the new programmers see everything in detail, you *may* want to include the `-verbose` option, which tells *javac* to output very detailed messages, including each class that is loaded and each source code file that is compiled.

So, bringing that all together, your *javac* command line would look like:

```
javac -classpath . -d ./classes -g -verbose
```

With the understanding that I have not included the option to list each source code file on the command line or used the **@** argument to reference a file that contains a list of the filenames. I personally have never used that option and it feels a little overly complicated I guess. Hope this is helpful -

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort you put into this answer!  Really appreciate your level of interest in explaining it.  I'll dig into this a bit further as I think this does the trick.

Comment: how is that the *best way* if you compare it to doing it with ant, maven, and especially new generation build tools like gradle? It might be the simplest to explain and understand, but best? It's certainly not the convention either to use javac every time.

Comment: @eis Given the OP's wish to start by running from the shell, I was offering my thoughts about what would be best _working within those constraints_. When I started programming in Java, that was the only way it worked; IDEs for Java, Ant, etc. did not exist, although we did have the _make_ command line build utility. Of course I use an IDE, Ant or Maven, Jenkins, Nexus, etc. each day at work, but that wasn't the context of the question. If you read my answer in the context of the question, it's obvious I wasn't making a general statement about the best way to compile Java code.

Comment: @SeanMickey well, my opinion is that it really isn't obvious. I would add "given the limitations expressed in the question, the best way probably is" or something like that to the first sentence, because otherwise, I don't really see how it would be best of anything. I think given the constraints using javac is pretty much only thing possible, so it would be equally true to claim it as the worst option.

Comment: I have added the phrase "Given the constraint to only work within a command shell" to the 1st sentence of my answer, to clarify the scope of my answer and to address the concerns raised by @eis (and to avoid argumentative comment pollution).

Comment: Hey @SeanMickey, I had to hold off on this for the last several days with simply being busy and I ended up trying several iterations of this to no avail.  I think it is close, but it did not quite work. Would you mind terribly checking out the source and seeing if you could get an incantation to work out from within the co (`miniventure`) folder (ie, the parent checkout folder)?